# Function highcharter::hciconarray doesn't work in R

Tags: r, r-highcharter

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

hciconarray(c("car", "truck", "plane"), c(75, 30, 20), icons = c("car", 
"truck", "plane")) %>%
  hc_add_theme(
    hc_theme_merge(
    hc_theme_flatdark(),
    hc_theme_null(chart = list(backgroundColor = "#34495e"))
  )
)
```

But, when I process:

[image]

The icons do not appear. 
What are the possible causes for this problem?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem, icons appear ok when I run the code. Maybe try updating your package?

Comment: I did that, but the error remains.